# Sql Server 2008 Update column with a join

Tags: sql-server, join, sql-update

I have done a lot of updating with MySql and have read a lot of questions and answers on here, but for some reason haven't been able to get my code to work.
I keep getting Err 42000 incorrect syntex near Inner, or anything I put here.
My code

```
Update
    Table1
Inner Join
    Table2 on Table2.column = Table1.column
Set
    Table1.column = 'Random'
Where
    table1.ID = '32'
```

Answer (score 3):

You are nearly there...

```
Update  Table1
   Set   Table1.column = 'Random'
FROM Table1 
Inner Join  Table2 on Table2.column = Table1.column
Where  table1.ID = '32'
```

An aliased version would look something like.....

```
Update  T1
    Set   T1.column = 'Random'
FROM Table1 T1 
Inner Join  Table2 T2 on T2.column = T1.column
Where  T1.ID = '32'
```

Comment: This somewhat worked.  To test I decided to do it against 1 specific account, I no longer get the Error Code but it doesn't update any accounts.

Answer (score 1):

You're close. It's your syntax for your `UPDATE` statement. Try this:

```
UPDATE [Table1]
SET [Column] = 'Random'
FROM [Table1]
INNER JOIN [Table2] ON [Table2].[column] = [Table1].[column]
WHERE [Table1].[ID] = '32'
```